$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp{(x+iy)}$
We can write $\exp{(x+iy)}=e^x\cdot e^{iy}$. Therefor, the limit is
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\exp{(x+iy)}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{e^x}\cdot e^{iy}=\infty\cdot e^{iy}$$
My question is: what is this and what its image ?
And what about $y\to\infty$? Is something undefined because y works as angle?

What do you mean by "whole complex level"? But yes, neither limit exists because neither one approaches a particular complex number. As $x \to \infty$, the modulus diverges. Whereas increasing $y$ corresponds to rotating around the circle of radius $e^x$ at a fixed angular velocity, so the motion never "stops" at some complex number.

@infinitylord ok thank you. With whole complex level i meant every possible complex number but now i see this statement is inaccurate given that the modulo goes to $\infty$.

$\lim_{x\to\infty}{e^x}\cdot e^{iy}$ converges to complex infinity.  Or we may say it diverges to complex infinity?

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \exp(x + iy)$ diverges to infinity in a direction on the complex plane that is determined by the value of $y$. We could write that as $\infty \cdot \exp(iy)$ as shorthand if we wanted to as long as we understand what we're representing with that.
On the other hand, $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \exp(x + iy)$ diverges, but not to infinity. It's similar to the discrete limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (-1)^n$ which oscillates between $1$ and $-1$, but in this case as $y$ increases you get values that spin around the circle $|z| = \exp(x)$.
